# Lit app with Vite - fonts and svg not loaded

Tags: vite, lit

I am new to Lit and Vite which I am currently using in my app.
Here is my slightly shortened files structure

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ assets/
|  |    |-fonts/
|  |    |   myfont.eot
|  |    |   myfont.ttf
|  |    |   myfont.woff
|  |    |   myfont.woff2
|  |    |-svg/
|  |    |   svg1.svg
|  |    |-css/
|  |    |   styles.js   
│  ├─ myComponent.ts   
├─ index.html
├─ vite.config.ts
├─ package.json
```

in the styles file I imports fonts like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "myfont";
    src: url("../fonts/myfont.eot?44307240");
    src: url("../fonts/myfont.eot?44307240#iefix")
        format("embedded-opentype"),
      url("../fonts/myfont.woff2?44307240") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/myfont.woff?44307240") format("woff"),
      url("../fonts/myfont.ttf?44307240") format("truetype"),
      url("../svg/svg1.svg?44307240#myfont") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

then I have a style defined

```
.my-icon:before {
    font-family: "myfont";
    content: "\e800";
  }
```

the content of which is unicode from the font that I want to be displayed when using it

This is my vite config file.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/myComponent.ts",
      formats: ["es"],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [/^lit/],
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": "./src",
    },
  },
  assetsInclude: [
    "**/*.svg",
    "**/*.woff",
    "**/*.woff2",
    "**/*.ttf",
    "**/*.eot",
  ],
});
```

The problem I have is that unicode is not loaded when using the given style, the styles load correctly, but instead of the icon I can see e800. Looking in the developer tools and sources, I don't see the fonts and svg folders there, and in the network tab I don't see any font fetched same for the svg.

With pure html without vite and lit, loading works and the icon displays correctly.

Can I ask you for help in solving this problem?

I tried adding

```
assetsInclude: [
    "**/*.svg",
    "**/*.woff",
    "**/*.woff2",
    "**/*.ttf",
    "**/*.eot",
  ],
```

but it doesn't help. Also I was trying to move fonts to other packages but same result at the end.

Comment: I solved this problem using [unplugin-fonts](https://github.com/cssninjaStudio/unplugin-fonts)